# Why do I need a relative import in Heroku but not when running locally?

Tags: python, heroku

When running locally my Flask app, I can use a common import:

```
from models import MyModel
```

But when running on Heroku, I need to change it to:

```
from .models import MyModel
```

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why on Heroku this happens. But it has to do with the Python path.

If you specify the path where the app is on the Procfile, it will work.

Before:

```
web: gunicorn src.api:api
```

After:

```
web: gunicorn src.api:api --pythonpath=./src
```

Considering that the main file is named `api.py` and is located inside a folder called `src`.